# how to email a log4j log file

Tags: java, log4j

I want to send log files to a given email address. Here is how I tried it.But it didn't work.

```
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;   
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;  
import org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender;  

public class LogSender {  
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(test.class);  
    SMTPAppender appender = new SMTPAppender();   
    public test() {  
        try {  
            appender.setTo("receiver@gmail.com");  
            appender.setFrom("sender@gmail.com");  
            appender.setSMTPHost("smtp.gmail.com");  
                    appender.setSMTPUsername("sender@gmail.com");  
                    appender.setSMTPPassword("mypassword");   
            appender.setLocationInfo(true);  
            appender.setSubject("Test Mail From Log4J");  
            appender.setLayout(new PatternLayout());  
            appender.activateOptions();  
            logger.addAppender(appender);           
            logger.error("This is an error");  
        }  
        catch(Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
            logger.error("Thrown exception",e);  
        }  
    }   
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        LogSender l = new LogSender;        
    }  
}
```

There is an exceptions saying

```
    log4j:ERROR Error occured while sending e-mail notification.
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ee6sm12133321igc.6
```

Any one tell my where the problem is and how I can solve this or give me any working sample code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use secure connection: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=20777. Some links: http://www.tgerm.com/2010/05/log4j-smtpappender-gmail-custom.html, http://codelol.com/2009/09/log4j-smtpappender-and-authentication/

Comment: As you mentioned, gmail messaging needs a secure connection.Then it was solved. Thank you very much.